# How to set state from an interface?

Tags: interface, dart, flutter

I have a class implementing an interface

```
class _UserSignupInterface implements UserSignupInterface {
  @override
  void onSuccess() {

  }

  @override
  void onError(String message) {
  }
}
```

However, I have no means of changing a variable via setState() which I will be using to change a displayed text on my page.

I have attempted to extend the interface to my `_SignupSelectUsernamePageState` and calling change state inside the interface but it only results in an error, maybe setState() should not be called within an interface.

I have also tried placing the variable outside of the `StatefulWidget` and the `PageState`. But simply updating its value means nothing if I cannot use setState() inside the interface since it does not reflect changing the text on the page.

The interface is a callback I use for processing response data received from network requests.

What is the proper way of changing the `Text` Widget's text outside of the `StatefulWidget` and `PageState` (that extends that StatefulWidget)? Since I have to handle the processing of data and updating of variables within the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `setState` should only be called within the widget itself.

In flutter, Google makes a difference between Ephemeral and App State

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app

Since you want your login to be global, you want App State.

There are many ways to manage it - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Redux - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux

Scope Model - https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model

Bloc - https://felangel.github.io/bloc/#/

Mobx - https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart

Do everything manually.

Example Stocks - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/stocks

In the child you need this.

```
class StockSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const StockSettings(this.configuration, this.updater);

  final StockConfiguration configuration;
  final ValueChanged<StockConfiguration> updater;

  @override
  StockSettingsState createState() => StockSettingsState();
}

class StockSettingsState extends State<StockSettings> {
void _handleBackupChanged(bool value) {
    sendUpdates(widget.configuration.copyWith(backupMode: value ? BackupMode.enabled : BackupMode.disabled));
}

void sendUpdates(StockConfiguration value) {
    if (widget.updater != null)
      widget.updater(value);
}
```

In the parent, you pass down configuartion updator which is just a wrapper around set state

```
class StocksAppState extends State<StocksApp> {
  StockData stocks;

  StockConfiguration _configuration = StockConfiguration(
    stockMode: StockMode.optimistic,
    backupMode: BackupMode.enabled,
    debugShowGrid: false,
    debugShowSizes: false,
    debugShowBaselines: false,
    debugShowLayers: false,
    debugShowPointers: false,
    debugShowRainbow: false,
    showPerformanceOverlay: false,
    showSemanticsDebugger: false
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    stocks = StockData();
  }

  void configurationUpdater(StockConfiguration value) {
    setState(() {
      _configuration = value;
    });
}

routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
         '/':         (BuildContext context) => StockHome(stocks, _configuration, configurationUpdater),
         '/settings': (BuildContext context) => StockSettings(_configuration, configurationUpdater)
},
```

Your choice.